# Existence of integer sequence under simultaneous constraints

Tags: integer-sequences, recurrences

Does there exist a function $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ such that \begin{align}a_{n+1}&=f(a_n)\\a_{f(n)+1}&=a_n\end{align} implies $\{a_n\}_{n\ge0}$ is a non-constant, positive integer sequence? Evidently $f$ cannot be monotonic.

If there is such a function, can all such $f$ be classified?

Comment: I'm assuming you also want such a sequence $a_n$ to exist - otherwise the implication is vacuously true.

Comment: $f$ defined by $f(0)=1,f(2k-1)=2k,f(2k)=2k-1$ for all $k>0$ seems to work. I have no idea about classification.

Comment: If there is a fixpoint $f(m)=m$ then $f(a_m) = a_{m+1} = a_{f(m)+1} = a_m$ and the sequence has a non-constant prefix followed by a constant tail.